# No render display

Tags: rendering

I need help please ,i do not know what i did wrong but i cannot view any render anymore

Here is the blend file https://files.fm/u/ggsrxfnp#_

(tell me if the link do not work)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. Add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings. Don't make the question depend on others downloading your file just to understand what you are asking.

Comment: @MaiSasaki This is a community dedicated towards learning from each other, not a "fix my file on demand". As it stands this question is too localized and won't help anyone else besides you. If you just want a fix it is probably better to ask over at [Blender Artists](https://blenderartists.org)

Comment: @MaiSasaki the comment is meant to help you get the answer you need. If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you.

Comment: Please describe what happens when you hit F12. Is the rendered image black, gray, pink or transparent. If you show the settings you are using then it is easier to determine what is going on.

Comment: in your camera settings > Depth of Field > Aperture, switch from F-Stop to Radius

Comment: You could start from reading rules of this site as you seem to be misunderstanding what it's intended for. People on this site do this as volunteers; don't expect others to do work for you while you post a link to the file and "fix this for me" comment. Comment above means exactly what it tells - it asks for more information.

Answer (score 3):

in the *Data* menu of your camera > *Depth of Field* > *Aperture*, switch from *F-Stop* to *Radius*, or set distance to be something other than 0.00

[image]

Comment: Or set distance to be something other than 0.00